# How can I change the password policy of MS SQL Server inside docker?

Tags: sql-server, docker

I'm stuck at simplifying the required password for MS SQL Server docker.

It requires:

1. Uppercase
2. Lowercase
3. Number
4. Symbol

I want to only provide lowercase letters for my development environment.

How can I configure that?

Comment: You can't change the policy. If you want to use a password deemed insecure, then define `CHECK_POLICY` as `OFF` when you create the `LOGIN`/`USER`.

Answer (score 0):

You can edit the SA_PASSWORD in the docker-compose.ymlfile.
It will be something like this:
environment:
- SA_PASSWORD=PasSw0rd